# Unable to get the response in POST method in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am facing a unique problem.
Following is my code.

```
url = 'ABCD.com'
cookies={'cookies':'xyz'}
r = requests.post(url,cookies=cookies)
print(r.status_code)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print("Printing =  ",json_data)
```

When I use the url and cookie in the POSTMAN tool and use POST request I get JSON response . But when I use the above code with POST request method in python I get 
404
Printing =   {'title': 'init', 'description': "Error: couldn't find a device with id: xxxxxxxxx in ABCD: d1"}

But when I use the following code i .e with GET request method

```
url = 'ABCD.com'
cookies={'cookies':'xyz'}
r = requests.post(url,cookies=cookies)
print(r.status_code)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print("Printing =  ",json_data)
```

I get 
200
Printing =   {'apiVersion': '0.4.0'}

I am not sure why POST method works with JSON repsone in POSTMAN tool and when I try using python it is not work. I use latest python 3.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong following is correct way

```
 url = 'ABCD.com'
cookies={'cookies':'xyz'}
r = requests.post(url,headers={'Cookie'=cookies)
print(r.status_code)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print("Printing =  ",json_data)
```

web page was expecting headers as cookie and i got the response correctly